# calling soap with jboss does not work

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss

I have a problem when my application call a soap web service when it is runnig in jboss server but i don't have this problem neither in soapUI or in local environment(with jetty server).

The problem is that i don't have access to the logs of the web service to analyse the problem. I use Gwt in client side.

In jboss i got this error:

```
18/06/2018 17:04:25,179 [http-pcdv.grouperci.com-138.21.231.126-57060-2] INFO com.rcibanque.socle.server.service.data.DataModuleServiceImpl  -  [CODE=263]  [USER=CHARRET MONGAY V_263]  [CURRENT=azsw5O-AwsNopMxxzQQ-I6+L.undefined]  [ID=azsw5O-AwsNopMxxzQQ-I6+L.undefined71]  [RANDOM=71] Ident1Controller:connexion:saveConnexion(263) COMMITED
18/06/2018 17:04:38,190 [http-pcdv.grouperci.com-138.21.231.126-57060-4] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/rci_pcd]  - Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call: com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract com.rcibanque.pcd.shared.beans.viewobject.bcc.BccWsResponseVO com.rcibanque.pcd.client.service.bcc.BCCServiceRpc.getEngagementBCC(com.rcibanque.pcd.shared.beans.viewobject.bcc.PcdWsRequestVO)' threw an unexpected exception: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
               at com.rcibanque.socle.server.filter.GWTCacheControlFilter.doFilter(GWTCacheControlFilter.java:42)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
               at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
               at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
               at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
               at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
               at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
               at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
               at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
               at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:150)
               at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:141)
               at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
               at com.rcibanque.pcd.server.ws.bcc.BCCWsServiceService.<init>(BCCWsServiceService.java:44)
               at com.rcibanque.pcd.server.service.bcc.BCCServiceRpcImpl.getEngagementBCC(BCCServiceRpcImpl.java:28)
               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
               ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:94)
               at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:204)
               at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:148)
               ... 31 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
at [row,col,system-id]: [1,0,"http://uaprca.mc2.renault.fr/bcc/BCCWsServiceService?wsdl"]
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:240)
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:191)
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
               ... 33 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
at [row,col,system-id]: [1,0,"http://uaprca.mc2.renault.fr/bcc/BCCWsServiceService?wsdl"]
               at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:677)
               at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2104)
               at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2010)
               at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1102)
               at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1077)
               at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:971)
               at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:898)
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:231)
               ... 35 more

18/06/2018 17:04:38,190 [http-pcdv.grouperci.com-138.21.231.126-57060-2] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/rci_pcd]  - Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call: com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract com.rcibanque.pcd.shared.beans.viewobject.bcc.BccWsResponseVO com.rcibanque.pcd.client.service.bcc.BCCServiceRpc.getEngagementBCC(com.rcibanque.pcd.shared.beans.viewobject.bcc.PcdWsRequestVO)' threw an unexpected exception: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
               at com.rcibanque.socle.server.filter.GWTCacheControlFilter.doFilter(GWTCacheControlFilter.java:42)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
               at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
               at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
               at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
               at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
               at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
               at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
               at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
               at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:150)
               at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:141)
               at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
               at com.rcibanque.pcd.server.ws.bcc.BCCWsServiceService.<init>(BCCWsServiceService.java:44)
               at com.rcibanque.pcd.server.service.bcc.BCCServiceRpcImpl.getEngagementBCC(BCCServiceRpcImpl.java:28)
               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
               ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:94)
               at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:204)
               at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:148)
               ... 31 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
at [row,col,system-id]: [1,0,"http://uaprca.mc2.renault.fr/bcc/BCCWsServiceService?wsdl"]
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:240)
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:191)
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
               ... 33 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
at [row,col,system-id]: [1,0,"http://uaprca.mc2.renault.fr/bcc/BCCWsServiceService?wsdl"]
               at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:677)
               at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2104)
               at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2010)
               at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1102)
               at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1077)
               at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:971)
               at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:898)
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:231)
               ... 35 more

18/06/2018 17:04:43,697 [http-pcdv.grouperci.com-138.21.231.126-57060-3] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/rci_pcd]  - Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call: com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract com.rcibanque.pcd.shared.beans.viewobject.bcc.BccWsResponseVO com.rcibanque.pcd.client.service.bcc.BCCServiceRpc.getEngagementBCC(com.rcibanque.pcd.shared.beans.viewobject.bcc.PcdWsRequestVO)' threw an unexpected exception: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
               at com.rcibanque.socle.server.filter.GWTCacheControlFilter.doFilter(GWTCacheControlFilter.java:42)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
               at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
               at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
               at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
               at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
               at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
               at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
               at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
               at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:150)
               at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:141)
               at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
               at com.rcibanque.pcd.server.ws.bcc.BCCWsServiceService.<init>(BCCWsServiceService.java:44)
               at com.rcibanque.pcd.server.service.bcc.BCCServiceRpcImpl.getEngagementBCC(BCCServiceRpcImpl.java:28)
               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
               at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
               ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:94)
               at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:204)
               at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:148)
               ... 31 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
at [row,col,system-id]: [1,0,"http://uaprca.mc2.renault.fr/bcc/BCCWsServiceService?wsdl"]
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:240)
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:191)
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
               ... 33 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
at [row,col,system-id]: [1,0,"http://uaprca.mc2.renault.fr/bcc/BCCWsServiceService?wsdl"]
               at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:677)
               at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2104)
               at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2010)
               at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1102)
               at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1077)
               at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:971)
               at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:898)
               at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:231)
               ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The application is trying to read the WSDL from http://uaprca.mc2.renault.fr/bcc/BCCWsServiceService?wsdl and fails. Perhaps you can access that address internally but not from the JBoss server? If you can login to the server, try to access it with curl or wget without proxy and see if that works.

I would keep a copy of the WSDL in the application and make sure it is used (set wsdlLocation). Of course, if you can't make the call later on that won't help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the jboss server can access to the wsdl when i debug on remote.

Comment: It complains about end of file at the first character (row=1, col=0), so it sounds very much like a network issue.

Comment: if it is a network issue , why it works when i run in jetty in local test?  Thanks.

Comment: If there is one thing that is different it is the network. Proxy servers (or not), firewalls, whatever. It could be something else, but the parser fails with end of file on the first byte in the WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this piece

```
at [row,col,system-id]: [1,0
```

exists in your log is an indicator of empty data(wsdl), or error while parsing the beginning of the file(wsdl).

Any one correct me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this problem by replacing ?wsdl by .wsdl in the url.